# Artefacts in 3D-Plots when z-values exceed z-axis limits?

Tags: pgfplots

When plotting an expression using `pgfplots`, there are strange artefacts in places where the z-values are too big for the current axis. How do I fix it? Is there an equivalent to `y domain` for the z-axis?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,
    ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
    zmin=0, zmax=1,
    view={40}{20}]
    \addplot3[domain=-1.5:1.5, y domain=-1.5:1.5,
    surf,samples=40,opacity=0.3]
    {1-x^2-y^2};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with Miktex 2.9 and using SumatraPDF or Adobe Acrobat X. Everything is clipped properly.

Comment: If I use TexLive 2011 and the IDE Gummi then I get the same problem as Psirus. If I use TexLive 2011 and the IDE TexWorks then everything is clipped properly.

Comment: Seems to be reader related. I was using evince, but it’s fine under Adobe Acrobat. Thank you guys. What’s the protocol here…close, delete, answer?

Comment: @Psirus: Close as _too localized_. I'll submit the first vote.